# Creating reusable FooterView for different TableViews (Swift 5)

Tags: ios, swift, tableview, tablefooterview

I created class FooterView: UIView. I use it to create FooterView for my TableView. But also I'd like to reuse this class to create FooterView in my other TableViews. When I try to add an argument to the setupElements () function to pass the required TableView there and change the Label text depending on it, but the initializer does not allow me to do this.
How can i do this? Also, Swift doesn't allow me to directly call the setupElements () function even when I remove the "private". My code:

```
class FooterView: UIView { 
    private var footerLabel: UILabel = {
        ...
    }()

    private func setupElements() {
        addSubview(footerLabel)
        ...
        footerLabel.text = "Table is empty"
    }
    
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        setupElements()
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}
...
class TableViewController: UIViewController {
   private lazy var footerView = FooterView()
   private var array: [String] = []

   func viewDidLoad() {
      super.viewDidLoad()
      setupTableView()
   }

   private func setupTableView() {
      tableView.register(UINib(nibName: "Cell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: LibraryCell.reuseId)
      if array.count == 0 {
         tableView.tableFooterView = footerView
      }
   }
}

extension TableViewController: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {...}
```

Comment: *"pass the required TableView"* -- makes no sense... why would you be trying to pass a tableView reference to your `FooterView`? *"Swift doesn't allow me to directly call the setupElements () function even when I remove the "private""* -- also makes no sense. Show your actual code... what you've posted doesn't even have a `tableView`.

Comment: This is the usual ViewController on which the TableView is located. Added this to the body of the question. I just want to place FooterView and have its footerLabel have different string values depending on which TableView it is: TableViewOne or TableViewTwo and so on.
I could create different FooterView classes for each of my TableViews, but this is not rational, I want to reuse one class. Is it clearer now?))

Comment: Are you saying you have two (or more) tableViews added as subviews to your `UIViewController`'s view? Or are you saying you have a `UITableViewController` in one place in your app, a different `UITableViewController` in another place, and so on?

Comment: Yes, I have a UITableViewController in one place in my app, a different UITableViewController in another place.

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of searching, I solved my problem. I removed the initialization and create a FooterView through the setupFooterView function (for vc: UIViewController) into which I pass the ViewController I need as a parameter. The code looks like this:

```
class FooterView: UIView {
    private var footerLabel: UILabel = {
        let label = UILabel()
        ...
        return label
    }()

    func setupFooterView(for vc: UIViewController) -> UIView {
        let footerView = UIView()
        footerView.addSubview(footerLabel)
        ...
        if vc is TableViewController {
        footerLabel.text = "..."
        } else if vc is SecondTableViewController {
            footerLabel.text = "..."
        }
        return footerView
    }
}
```

Adding FooterView to the ViewController I need:

```
...
private lazy var footerView = FooterView()
...
tableView.tableFooterView = footerView.setupFooterView(for: self)
```